# Binary search of an array of arrays in Lua

Tags: lua, binary-search

I have written a binary search function in Lua from my memory of how it works in Python which works on a single array (table).

```
    function bisect_left(a, x, lo, hi)
        lo = lo or 1
        hi = hi or nil
        if lo < 0 then
            error('lo must be non-negative')
        end
        if hi == nil then
            hi = #a
        end
        while lo < hi do
            mid = math.floor((lo+hi) / 2)
            if a[mid] < x then 
                lo = mid+1
            else
                hi = mid
            end
        end
        return lo
     end
```

but then I encountered needing to search a sorted array of arrays (table of tables). They are sorted by index 1

```
squares = {{300, 400, 123456, 9}, {400, 500, 323456, 9}, {420, 610, 5123456, 9}, {530, 700, 8123456, 9}, {840, 960, 9123456, 1}}
```

In Python I would do something like overload the comparison operator **cmp** like

```
Class overload(object):
    def __init__(self, value, index):
        self.value = value
        self.index = index
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp(self.value, other[self.index])
```

What is the fastest way to do this in Lua? I can think of (I presume) slow ways to do it but my functional programming inexperience makes me wonder if there is a way I would never guess.

Comment: Shouldn't return lo be after the loop, not inside the loop?

Comment: I, guess, You could use `__eq`, `__le` and `__lt` [Metatable events](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MetatableEvents) for this purpose. And `__newindex` for generating proper table.

Trying to come up with simple explanatory code snippet.

Comment: thanks dasblinkenlight! Been writing lua for 1 day and all the "end"'s keep tripping me up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, look at what's your comparator in the first example. Let's take a simple line:

```
if lo < 0 then
```

This could be written as something like:

```
if numericCompare(lo, 0) then
```

`numericCompare` being obviously `function numericCompare(a,b) return a < b end`.

Well then, change all the comparisons to something you might call `tableCompare`, and implement said comparator, presumably as

```
function tableCompare(a,b)
    return a[1] < b[1]
end
```

In general, `tab[1]` access should be rather fast due to the nature of Lua's tables. Code it, profile, and only then try to optimize.

Yoy can overload operators in Lua, but in that case I think that taking the comparator as parameter and naming it explicitely is slightly more readable.